# html form not submitting large string to php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, http-post

I want to send very large string data to php using form submit as I want to write it to file and force download it using php content desposition headers. however, php POST var is not getting complete string. In addition, if I use $.post , PHP $_post receives complete string. But i don't want to use $.post as php return that string to javascript.

PHP code

```
$content = $_POST["filestring"];
$content = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'.$content;       
$length = strlen($content);

header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename.'.' . $ext);
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: ' . $length);
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: public');
echo $content;
exit;
```

JAVASCRIPT code ----

```
var form = '<form id="xml_export_form" action="assets/plugins/vocera/fileHelper.php" 
enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input type="hidden" name="filestring" value="">
<input type="text" name="filetype" value = "xml">
<input type="text" name="filename" value = "'+fileName+'">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>';
$('#xml_export_form').find('input[name="filestring"]').first().val(xmlDocStr);      
$('#xml_export_form').submit();
```

Comment: What does `var_dump(ini_get('post_max_size'));` output? You might want to increase the limit if it's too low. See [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) for more details.

Comment: i had the same kind of issue when i was getting the string from mssql database ,the string was breaking .I split the string into two parts with query and then just did the concatenation on the front end

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to change the size allowed for post.

You can increase the maximum size of the post in one of two places.

php.ini

```
post_max_size=XXXM
upload_max_filesize=XXXM
```

or .htaccess

```
php_value post_max_size XXXM
php_value upload_max_filesize XXXM
```

[Docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size)

Comment: @asprin `ini_set()` only changes it for the lifetime of the script. This will more than likely be recurring so he may as well set it permanently.

Comment: May I ask what the down vote was for? Feedback would be appreciated then I can change what was wrong..

Comment: I didn't say you was, it was directed at the mystery downvoter :)

Comment: upload_max_filesize set to 20M also. still no luck

Comment: @Stanyer - Given the heat in another thread in this topic, I am sure we both know who it was ;)

Comment: @ssj what is the size of your string?

Comment: in JS string length is 42316672

Comment: @ssj - Thats just over 40MB. Hence why your 20MB limit isn't working.

Comment: ya thanks. Now i increased the limit to 60MB and using $.post to send the string to php and and in php am echoing the lenth of post var . However, it is not posting that amount of data. it is giving error in jquery.min js

Comment: You might need to be more specific about your error. I can't help from 'it is giving error'...

Answer (score 0):

You can set the maximum post size in your .htaccess file if you are using linux

```
php_value post_max_size 10M
```

or in the .ini file if you are using windows

```
  php_value post_max_size=10M
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware - you can do either of these, in either of those OS's.

Comment: I'm sure my comment made perfect sense... May you elaborate on why you should the htaccess file for linux, and the ini file for windows?

Comment: You can use both! The htaccess or the ini file, so no need for the down vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote. I was simply asking why you are recommending to use the htaccess file for linux, or the ini file for windows.

Comment: Well who ever down voted this answer can at least give an explanation. htaccess is the file I usually edit when I'm using Linux, so that is why I suggested it.

Comment: But you've no reason to specify that you should change the .htaccess on linux, but if you're on windows, change the .ini file. It's misleading. That was my only question.

Comment: Changed. Happy?? @Stanyer

Comment: I already worked on that. my post_max_size  is set to 20M. still no luck. I am using wamp

Comment: @user65439 I was never 'unhappy'. I was just curious as to why you specified that htaccess was for linux, and php ini was for windows - as I hadn't heard of that before. However you couldn't explain, you got angry, and decided to downvote me.